# how to target and modify a batch of properties within a typescript class

Tags: angular, typescript

How can i simplify all this code.  i wish to have one function perform the task below.

should be a simple task i am just fulfilling in more text here as stackoverflow demands more text.  Please try to resolve  thanks so much! typescript is an awesome language. its a little more different than javascript. when i attempted my own method for trying to resolve the below i got undefined...its hard trying to figure out how to group, target and change the values

```js
class foods {
    private apple: boolean;
    private banana: boolean;
    private guava: boolean;
    private passionfruit: boolean;
    private melon: boolean;
    private oranges: boolean;
    private porkchop: boolean;
    private steak: boolean;
    private chicken: boolean;

    toggleApple() {
        this.apple = true;
        this.banana = false;
        this.guava = false;
        this.passionfruit = false;
        this.melon = false;
        this.oranges = false;
    }

    toogleBanana() {
        this.apple = false;
        this.banana = true;
        this.guava = false;
        this.passionfruit = false;
        this.melon = false;
        this.oranges = false;
    }

    toggleGuava() {
        this.apple = false;
        this.banana = false;
        this.guava = true;
        this.passionfruit = false;
        this.melon = false;
        this.oranges = false;
    }

    togglePassionFruit() {
        this.apple = false;
        this.banana = false;
        this.guava = false;
        this.passionfruit = true;
        this.melon = false;
        this.oranges = false;
    }

    toggleMelon() {
        this.apple = false;
        this.banana = false;
        this.guava = false;
        this.passionfruit = false;
        this.melon = true;
        this.oranges = false;
    }

    toggleOranges() {
        this.apple = false;
        this.banana = false;
        this.guava = false;
        this.passionfruit = false;
        this.melon = false;
        this.oranges = true;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can allocate everything into a single function. I'm sure there would be much more creative solutions, though this solution would at least put all the logic into a single toggle function.

```
apple: boolean;
banana: boolean;
guava: boolean;
passionfruit: boolean;
melon: boolean;
oranges: boolean;
porkchop: boolean;
steak: boolean;
chicken: boolean;

constructor(
) {
    this.apple = false;
    this.banana = false;
    this.guava = false;
    this.passionfruit = false;
    this.melon = false;
    this.oranges = false;
}

toggleFruit(fruitName: string) {
    (fruitName === 'apple' ? this.apple = true : this.apple = false);
    (fruitName === 'banana' ? this.banana = true : this.banana = false);
    (fruitName === 'guava' ? this.guava = true : this.guava = false);
    (fruitName === 'passionfruit' ? this.passionfruit = true : this.passionfruit = false);
    (fruitName === 'melon' ? this.melon = true : this.melon = false);
    (fruitName === 'oranges' ? this.oranges = true : this.oranges = false);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make an Array of Objects. Where the object consist of two properties: name and status.

Something Like this:

```
   foodList = [
      { name: 'Apple', status: false },
      { name: 'Banana', status: false }
      ...
    ];
```

The name property is the name of the food, and the status property is if the food is true or false.

After, create an method where you pass as a param the food name.

```
toogleFood(foodName: string) {
   this.foodList.map( food => {
      if (food.name === foodName) {
         food.status = true;
      }
   });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
class foods {
    private active: string[] = [];

    toggleApple() {
        this.toggleFood('apple');
    }

    toggleBanana() {
        this.toggleFood('banana');
    }

    toggleGuava() {
        this.toggleFood('guava');
    }

    togglePassionFruit() {
        this.toggleFood('passion fruit');
    }

    toggleMelon() {
        this.toggleFood('melon');
    }

    toggleOranges() {
        this.toggleFood('oranges');
    }

    private toggleFood(name: string): void {
        if (this.active.includes(name)) {
            this.active = this.active.filter((activeName) => activeName !== name);
        } else {
            this.active.push(name);
        }
    }
}
```